# GreenRobot EventBus error : No subscribers registered for event

Tags: android, service, greenrobot-eventbus

I am trying to post event from Activity to Service using [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).
But when I try to post event the logcat is showing the following message :

```
No subscribers registered for event class com.example.dhaval.homeexamples.CallBackEvent
No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

Here is code which I used in Activity to post event :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new CallBackEvent(1));
```

Following is my `CallBackEvent` :

```
public class CallBackEvent {
  private int a;
  public CallBackEvent(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Following is my Service class having Subscriber :

```
public class BackService extends Service{

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  }

  @Subscribe
  public void onEvent(CallBackEvent callBackEvent){
    Log.d("service", "CallBackEvent : called");
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? Because when I post event from Service to Activity it is working fine. But, when I try with this code (From Service to Activity) it is not working.

Comment: I am trying to post an event from a service to a fragment but I have ran into this issue; I have no idea what I need to do now

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, the code is as follows:

```
if(!EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(CallBackEvent.class)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to answer of @jdsjlzx
i have done it with another way

```
if (EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(CharSequence.class)) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(someCharSequenceVar);
}
```

So simply do not send event if there is no subscriber registered

Answer (score 0):

Check that your service is actually running when your activity posts the event.

Also, rather than trying to post an event to a service why not just start it with an intent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to only register the subscriber once. So, registering in onCreate move on to onStart() like below:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

Instead, you need to move the unregistering before super.onDestroy() called:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```